# Sum only if all grouped rows are not null, else return null

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
 item_id   quantity
 1         2
 1         3
 2         NULL
 2         4
 3         NULL
 3         NULL
```

And now I'm doing a SELECT like this:

```
SELECT 
   sum(`quantity`) AS `total_quantity`,
FROM `items`
GROUP BY `item_id`
```

Now, it return repectively 5, 4, and NULL, but I want 5, NULL and NULL.

I want that if there is a NULL value in the grouped rows, the sum should be NULL, and not the sum of the lines whose columns are not null. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: post your expected output for provided data set

Comment: I could only achieve not returning any row that contains NULL. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @thanyaj I already had that, but I need those lines too. I need to figure out a way to know if some lines in the sum are NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only `case` statement to check if any row of a group contains `null` as quantity

```
SELECT item_id,
     CASE WHEN SUM(quantity IS NULL) > 0 
     THEN NULL 
     ELSE SUM(quantity) 
     END quantity
FROM items
GROUP BY item_id
```

using @Abhik Chakraborty's fiddle

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccb36/15)

Comment: As always @M Khalid Junaid thats was smart :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and it avoids using subqueries. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Thats kind if weird output, in most cases the request is to replace null with 0 or something else, however here is a way to do it

```
select 
x.item_id,
max(x.quantity) as quantity from (
  SELECT 
  t1.item_id,
  @sm:= if(@prev_item = item_id, @sm_qty+quantity,quantity) as quantity,
  @prev_item :=item_id,
  @sm_qty:= quantity
  from items t1,(select @prev_item:=null,@sm_qty=0)x
  order by item_id
)x
group by x.item_id;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccb36/13

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    ( -- Get all not null quantities
        SELECT 
           `i1`.`item_id`,
           sum(`i1`.`quantity`) AS `total_quantity`
           FROM `items` AS `i1`
           WHERE `i1`.`item_id` NOT IN ( SELECT `i2`.`item_id` FROM `items` AS `i2` WHERE `i2`.`quantity` IS NULL )
        GROUP BY `item_id`
    )
    UNION ALL
    ( -- Get all null quantities
        SELECT 
           `i3`.`item_id`,
           null AS `i3`.`total_quantity`
           FROM `items` AS `i3`
           WHERE `i3`.`item_id` IN ( SELECT `i4`.`item_id` FROM `items` AS `i4` WHERE `i4`.`quantity` IS NULL )
        GROUP BY `i3.item_id`
    )
) AS items_table
ORDER BY items_table.item_id
```